# Cannot make a successful curl put call in PHP

Tags: http, php-curl, php-7.2

I am interacting with a external restful API. I was able to perform GET and POST requests successful but my PUT calls are acting strangely.

When I try to perform the task using Postman everything works as expected.

These are my postman parameters:

URl : https://externalapi.com.br/1/sales/0000-8021-46db-9919-8728fec13556/void?amount=15700

Headers: MerchantKey : mykey
Headers: MerchantId: myid

My "curl code" is like that:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://externalapi.com.br/1/sales/0000-8021-46db-9919-8728fec13556/void?amount=15700');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'MerchantId: ' .  $this->merchant_id,  'MerchantKey: ' .  $this->merchant_key ));


$res = null;

try{

    $res = curl_exec($ch);


}catch (Exception $e){

    return $e->getMessage();

}


return $res;
```

My curl code outputs this

```
 Length Required
 HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.
```

Comment: Oh, I solved it my adding "Content-Length: 0'" to the array of headers.

Answer (score 0):

I added 'Content-Length: 0' to the header. Only when using cUrl with PUT   this was necessary.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'MerchantId: ' .  $this->merchant_id,  'MerchantKey: ' .  $this->merchant_key, 'Content-Length: 0' ));
```